# Why do I have to suppress XML excaping in this scenario

Tags: html, css, jstl

I am working with a servlet that adds markup to text documents.
For example, it might produce the following sentence

according to `<span class="legalTerm">the plaintiff</span>` the contract was never signed

In my jsp I have the following css, html and jstl:

```
<style>
.legalTerm {
    background: lightgrey;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <c:out value="${document}"></c:out>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app the document that is displayed in the browser looks like:

```
according to <span class="legalTerm">the plaintiff</span> the contract was never signed
```

When I look at the page source I see:

```
according to &lt;span class=&#034;legalTerm&#034;&gt;the plaintiff&lt;/span&gt; the contract was never signed
```

I was able to get correct behavior by suppressing XML escaping

```
<c:out value="${document}"  escapeXml="false"></c:out>
```

My question is: is this how it should be done?
Or am I missing something that would eliminate the need to suppress XML escaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct behavior and why escapeXML exists -- to allow you to prevent the engine from escaping.   The default value for escapeXML is "true" as the typical use case would require it to be escaped.

Comment: Alfreema, thanks for the answer.  Do you know why the escaped HTML does not get rendered correctly by the browser?

Comment: When you escape the HTML, you are specifically telling the browser that instead of _rendering_ the HTML (in other words "interpreting" or "running" the HTML instruction), you would rather it display that string to the screen so that the user sees the HTML tag itself.   When it is not escaped, it tells the browser to actually interpret the HTML and do whatever the tag tells it to do.   Make sense?

Comment: Thanks again alfreema.  Does not quite make sense because the default, escapeXML="true" seems like the minority case.  But no worries, I'll do whatever it takes.  Thanks again for taking the time to explain.